# How can I make my bot delete any message sent in a channel after 1 second?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want my bot to delete any messages typed in a channel 1 second after it is sent.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Use `await ctx.send("message", delete_after=1)`. Refer [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await client.delete_message(message)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```